# Not fully evaluating in module?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How do I force evaluation of all symbols in a module?

```
vout[vin_] = Module[{x=vin,y},
    y = 200000*(1.2 - x);
    Print[y];
    y
];
Print[vout[0]];
```

I'm expecting this to print the same thing (240000) twice, but instead I'm getting this:

```
200000*(1.2 - vin)
240000.
```

Any idea what to do here to be able to get the expanded value (240000) while within the module?

Edit: `Print[Evaluate[y]];` will not work either in this case

Comment: Please see my answer below, but I suggest you use the new [Mathematica StackExchange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) forum for MMA related questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should type ":=" instead of "=", so that your function is recomputed correctly each time.

This works fine

vout[vin_] := Module[{x=vin,y},
    y = 200000*(1.2 - x);
    Print[y];
    y
];
Print[vout[0]];

Comment: Thanks, got it! I need to read http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html more carefully. Way too man operators...

Comment: I suggest you read the Mathematica book in pdf. You can find it in the wolfram site under legacy documentation. The latest is version 5.1 , but it does not matter. You will learn all the basics, the rest you can learn online. there is also a "book" in the online documentation.